# Flask Login: current_user is not working even after logging in the user

Tags: reactjs, flask, fetch-api, flask-login

I am creating a chat app in flask and react. In react, I call the login request and after the success return the chat page is shown which is asking for the current user rooms that user is currently joined in. But in flask, I'm getting this error.

```
192.168.100.9 - - [25/Dec/2023 17:01:55] "POST /get_rooms HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1478, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\engineio\middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "D:\PythonSTUFF\Python-flask-chat-app\routes.py", line 196, in get_rooms
    rooms = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first().rooms

AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'username'
```

In the login function, I have used flask_login.login_user() to logged in a user.

```
@main.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.get_json()['username']
        password = request.get_json()['password']
        
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(password):
                login_user(user)
                return jsonify({"status": "success"}), 200
        else:
            error = "Incorrect username or password"
    else:
        error = "Incorrect username or password"
            
    return jsonify({"status": "error", "message": error}), 500
```

After the success returned, the request for getting rooms is called where I am getting error.

```
@login_required
@main.route('/get_rooms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_rooms():
    rooms = User.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first().rooms
    rooms_data = []
    for room in rooms:
        rooms_data.append({'room_code': room.room_code, 'room_name': room.room_name, 'last_message': room.last_message, 'last_message_user': room.last_messsage_user, 'admin': room.admin})
    return jsonify({"status": "success", "rooms": rooms_data}), 200
```

This should return rooms for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Test if `get_json()` method is returning the correct data you want, because the error:

> AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'username'

states that there is no attribute named 'username', maybe no 'username' key found in that JSON.

Another thing is that, either the data in the request isn't sent properly, or it can't extract the data from the request.

Follow the documentation to know which function gets JSON data, or check your request again, Maybe the request method is causing the error.

Comment: The error is occurring on current_user that is used to get the current user of the request. Which is created after successful login of the user